# How to read the hard coded json data in controller file and display its value

Tags: json, angular, hardcoded

I am looking for a way to hardcode the json data in controller file and read the value and display it.

```
 var params = [
                    {
                            "id":1,
                            "title":"BA",
                            "name":"Kate"       
                    }
              ]
```

This is the json data I have in controller file.
How can i read the data and display it in console.

Comment: What is the problem? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is always going to be a single item, why are you making it an array? You could just do the following:

```
let params = {
  "id":1,
  "title":"BA",
  "name":"Kate"     
};
```

Then access the data like this:

```
params.id
params.title
params.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the item like this:

```
params[0].id
```

Comment: Thank you . I am sorry that I have created an array . Could you please tell me how to retrieve for a json

Comment: var params = '{
                            "id":1,
                            "title":"BA",
                            "name":"Kate"       
                    }'

Comment: You can use -> " params.id "